# Using name inside a Array yields different results in Firefox

Tags: javascript, arrays, keyword, reserved

I would like a little guidance here. Using *JS Bin* for this.
The whole issue here is : "name" when used as a VAR and inside an array:
---the console.log prints each letter:

```
var word = "Hi";
var name = ["John","Suzette","Mari-Louise","Tinus","Hendrik","Koos","Elna","Elbie"];
// Greeting
greeter(word,name);

function greeter(str,arr){
 var counter;
  for(counter = 0;
    counter < arr.length;
    counter++) {
    console.log(str + " " + arr[counter]);
    }
   }
```

*Output*

```
"Hi J"
"Hi o"
"Hi h"
"Hi n"
"Hi ,"
"Hi S"
"Hi u"
```

However, changing the VAR to userName, yields the correct result,..I cant find any reference to *'name'* being a reserved word in JS, so if someone could clarify this for me, it will be smashing.

```
var word = "Hi";
var userName = ["John","Suzette","Mari-Louise","Tinus","Hendrik","Koos","Elna","Elbie"];
// Greeting
greeter(word,userName);

function greeter(str,arr){
 var counter;
  for(counter = 0;
   counter < arr.length;
   counter++) {
   console.log(str + " " + arr[counter]);
    }
   }
```

Result**

```
"Hi John"
"Hi Suzette"
"Hi Mari-Louise"
"Hi Tinus"
"Hi Hendrik"
"Hi Koos"
"Hi Elna"
"Hi Elbie"
```

Comment: This question has been asked and answered many times here on SO. Please search harder. By the way, what do you mean by "using `name` inside an array"?

Comment: @torazaburo: I think this really is an unsearchable issue when you don't know what happens. Of course, `typeof name` could give you a hint, but still…

Comment: @Bergi You're right. I looked for the dup and could not find it. Can you?

Comment: @torazaburo https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=cast+name+string+window+%5Bjs%5D did work for me. But only because I cleaned up most of them myself :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you debug, you will notice that `name` is already defined by the time you execute your code. It happens because global `window` context has `name` property which is string.
When you try to set `["a", "b", "c"]` to this property, a browser converts it to a string, and it becomes `"a,b,c"`. That's why when you iterate through it, you get characters.

```js
console.log(name); // it already exists

var name = ["a", "b", "c"]; // assigns window.name property, becomes a string
var nameqwe = ["a", "b", "c"]; // creates local variable

console.log(name);
console.log(nameqwe);
```

Comment: No, it doesn't become `["a","b","c"]`?

Comment: No, it doesn't become `["a","b","c"]`. It becomes `"a,b,c"`.

Comment: @Bergi Yeah, my bad, it becomes `a,b,c`. It simply applies `[].toString()` :)

Comment: Ah, thanks - that makes sense

Comment: No, it does not become `"a","b","c"`. It becomes the string `"a,b,c"`.

Answer (score 0):

oh but 'name' is reserved:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp

look under JavaScript Objects, Properties, and Methods

Comment: Thanks Niles , clearly i need to sleep more "thumbs Up*...

Comment: ha! Life of a programmer, still I think it's a fascinating find.

Comment: No, it's not "reserved", which means something specific. It's a built-in property on `window`. I would not refer people to w3schools. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name) is a much more reliable resource.

Comment: [Keywords on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords) as well.